# Go to previous state without reload with history API?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, history.js

I have an image that, when clicked, goes full screen and pressing the browser back button minimizes it

[image]

OR any other `<button>` connected to the `fullscreen()` also minimizes it

so far I've come up with this:

```js
function fullscreen(show){
  if(show){
    ... # maximize image
    history.pushState({id:1},null)
  }
  else{
    ... # minimize image
    history.go(0)
  }
  
window.addEventListener("popstate",()=>{
  fullscreen(false)
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a47wf0p8/) (but you'll have to run it locally on an `.html` file)

but the problem is that this approach reloads the entire page
so is there a way to keep the page from reloading?